# How can I investigate extensions problems with Visual Studio for Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I click the Extensions I get nothing on one of my computers. I have checked the marketplace is not down. I have tried to delete the app and download a new version. Nothing helps. So are there any ways I can investigate this further? Quite frustrating to not been able to install extensions...

I'm on a Mac with Catalina 10.14.6 and I have VS for Code 1.41.1. I launched the Console app and see some messages from Electron(which I suspect is some part of VS for Code since it is mentioned in the about window) but none really makes sense.

Comment: Isn't there a proxy in your network which could block the requests of VS Code?